# Restore to keep training not working with tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I need to save and restore the graph to keep training from the last checkpoint, but somehow is not working.

I use `saver = tf.train.Saver()` to save the model. And:

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    # Initializing saver
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    save_path = saver.save(sess,model_path+"/%s.ckpt"%model_name)
    if flag == "initial_train":
        training_loop(num_epochs)
        flag = None
    else:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+"/%s.ckpt.meta"%model_name)
        new_saver.restore(sess, save_path)
        print("Model loaded")
        training_loop(num_epochs)
```

I really don't know why it's not importing the weights

Comment: You are saving unconditionally before loading, are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: well, if I want to train from the checkpoint I need all weights and the optimizer. But it doesn't seem to load anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are, on subsequent runs

1. Initializing all variables (so they will have their initial random/constant values) with `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()`
2. Saving the initialized values to some file (`saver.save(sess,model_path+"/%s.ckpt"%model_name)`)
3. Loading those randomly initialized values from that file

So you are just loading what you initialized and saved on line 3&4.

Also, I don't know how you pass information, but training_loop does not get a reference to the `saver` and you are not saving the model after the training loop, so it seems you are not actually saving your models anywhere.

Comment: Sorry  I didnt write the whole code, but inside the function training_loop I do saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step=epoch)

Comment: @florpi then you still have the first problem (you are just restoring the randomly intialized values you saved on line 4 of your snippet).